# css - render nested divs in different order (z-index?)

Tags: html, css

I want to have a nested div appear over its parent, while the parent has overflow-y: scroll

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
```

And the css:

```
#parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 70px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2; (????)
}
```

Want I would like to get is the red div to actually appear over and outside the green one without activation the overflow property. 
But it's just rendered over its parent, which then proceeds to overflow with the scrollbar. So it is over the parent, which it naturally is, but not outside it and I sadly can't just ditch the overflow-property. I just want to ignore it for that one element and pretty much change it to overflow: visible.

Comment: unclear what you are asking. Try to include a snippet and/or to edit your last paragraph. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Child cant exit parent's DIV. You need to use position:absolute, or even two different parent divs.

See here: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

And here's a css trick solutions: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Good luck, next time just post the code in jsFiddle.